# How to create a composite key as a unique key in Solr 7.2?

Tags: solr, solr4

I have following columns in Solr Schema - : 
imei,date, gpsdt, odo

Now I want to define (imei, date) as a unique key in Solr Schema.

How do i do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. add a new field: 'id'
2. send the right data to it, either by:

   1. on your client side, append the fields into 'id' and send it, or
   2. set up an UpdateRequestProcessor that populates the id field. check [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html) in case you can use some predefined URP and you can avoid having to write a custom one in java